# How to hide User Control div from aspx page?

Tags: javascript, c#

In my user control i have below controls :

**.ascx Page:**

```
<div id="div1" runat="server">
     <asp:Label ID="Lblname" Text="Name" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div id="div2" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtvalue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div id="div3" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Click" />
</div>
```

**aspx page** 
How to hide div1, div2 & div3 using c# or javascript

Comment: You can do like this. var divOne = document.getElementById('div1');
divOne.style.display='none';

Comment: I would like to set visibility from my aspx page. how to get this controls id from my aspx.

Comment: First you need to check ids of div in html, because if you are using masterpage then ids will change, and then use my javascript code

Comment: tried but not working

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of javascript. You can easily put an 
`id="YourId"` and `runat="server"`. You can also add a `Visible=False` as default (or the other way if you want it to be visible as default). In .cs page, you can define and change the Visible value as  you wish. So let's say you want it visible as a default only for administrator users, and you check in database if the user is an administrator with a true/false value (a bit value). then in PageLoad() you can perform a check like this:

```
if(LoggedUser.IsAdmin==true)
{
div1.Visible=true;
}
else 
{
div1.Visible=false;
}
```

Comment: I can't call div1 id from my aspx page. How to do that ?

Comment: If you need to call it in the codebehind of that same page, than use `div1.id` else, put it in a session like this:
`Session["div1"] = div1.id` and in the page you need it, call the Session["div1"] as a parameter and cast it as you need

Answer (score 0):

You page renders html from your user controls as well as from master pages.

If you want to hide your elements then simply use this

```
$("#YouHTMLElement").attr("style","display:none");
```

One important thing: you need to specify clientidmode="static" on your divs because IDs of server controls changes when your html renders.

**Updated:** In C#, you need to do this

```
  div1.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

Comment: Its not javascript solution. its jquery. in question its mentioned needs solution in c# or javascript.

Comment: then try ClientIDMode="Static" take care it is case sensitive

Comment: it's possible to do it using c#

Answer (score 0):

### A C# implementation

You should be able to reference your divs by their IDs in the codebehind since you have `runat` set to `server`.

So, assuming you want this to occur on the page loading, to your `Page_Load` event, add:

`div2.Visible = false;`

Comment: i would like to hide User control div from my parent page. how to do that ?